# How to pass a parameter to a javascript function on a JSF 2.0 page

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I am making a custom login dialog, similar to the one found on http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf but i get an error when building:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml @58,83 oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(#{securityController.logIn})": The class 'managedbeans.SecurityController' does not have the property 'logIn'.

I think the mistake is in the way i try to trigger the logging procedure. Could someone have a look if my syntax is correct?

```
  <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Login" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" width="400" resizable="false" draggable="false" fixedCenter="true">  
<h:form>    
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Em@il: *" />  
        <p:inputText value="#{securityController.email}"   
                id="email" required="true" label="email" />  

        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: * " />  
        <h:inputSecret value="#{securityController.password}"   
                id="password" required="true" label="password" />  

        <f:facet name="footer">  
            <p:commandButton value="Login" update="growl"                       
                oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(#{securityController.logIn})"/>  
        </f:facet>  
    </h:panelGrid>           
</h:form>  
</p:dialog> 
<script type="text/javascript">  
function handleLoginRequest(input) {  
    if(input == false) {  
        jQuery('#dialog').parent().effect("shake", { times:3 }, 100);  
    } else {  
        dlg.hide();  
        jQuery('#loginLink').fadeOut();  
    }  
 }  
</script>
```

And this the managed bean that holds the method that is being called onComplete event:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SecurityController {

@EJB
private IAuthentificationEJB authentificationEJB;
private String email;
private String password;
private String notificationValue;   

public void logIn() {
    if(authentificationEJB.saveUserState(email, password)) {
        notificationValue = "Dobro dosli";
    }   
}
    //getters and setters...
```

Comment: You can pass the parameter not the method to javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call your login method from the `actionListener` attribute of `p:commandButton` and not inside the `oncomplete` attribute. The javascript function from the example can be used without changes. It is only for displaying the effect.

Change your `p:commandButton` this way:

```
<p:commandButton value="Login" update="growl"                       
       oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)"
       actionListener="#{securityController.logIn}"
/>
```

And use the js function exactly as in the primefaces showcase:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) {  
        if(args.validationFailed || !args.loggedIn) {  
            jQuery('#dialog').parent().effect("shake", { times:3 }, 100);  
        } else {  
            dlg.hide();  
            jQuery('#loginLink').fadeOut();  
        }  
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: @sfrj with your case `#{securityController.logIn}` This will search for `getLogIn()` in `securityController` controller bean , you are passing it as value. @Matt +1

Comment: I did that and now i dont get build error. But when i click on the submit button i get an error. I think it has to do with the EJB. I will make an update to show you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute method on a javascript event then use `<a4j:jsfunction>`

Example [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/jsFunction.jsf;jsessionid=292EBD3CC6D8AC4EA36E324B7C24AEDC?c=jsFunction&tab=usage).

Comment: you forgot the link to the example

Comment: Is there any other alternative, i dont want to use richfaces. I had conflicts in the past with primefaces + rich faces together

Comment: @sfrj : then better add action to your commandbutton and oncomplete do the stuff you want passing any boolean variable set in action.